# Compile options -g debug and -O optimization

Tags: performance, compilation, g++, command-line-arguments

I am not quite familiar with g++ compilers, especially the options, e.g., -s, -g, and -O.

Firstly, can I ask when do these options take effect? During compile or link phase? I normally put all the options I need in both phases.

Secondly, are there -g1, -g2, -g3 options? I know -g adds debugging info in the to executable. How do others differ?

Thirdly, what does -s do? Do -s, -g, and -O3 work together? My target is to make the executable 1) run quickly, and 2) have small size if possible. What do you suggest?

Comment: do I apply all the options in the compile phase or link phase or both phases? Can I include the debug info -g in compile phase, and then apply the -O3 and -s in link phase? I don't know it this will work...

Comment: actually, I am writing a Makefile. I wonder if I can include debug information in compilation for creating object files, and then create two executable of different versions using the object files. Is it possible? thanks.

Comment: I think you are extending a bit this question. Yes, you can compile using "-ggdb -g3 -O3 -c" and then if you want to link for "release" you use "-O3 -s" and if you want to link for debug you use "-O3 -ggdb -g3 -O3". But why would you want such a thing? The saved disk space (and time) is not that much, and if you use O3 and debug it is not very clear. Maybe you should post another question explaining better your use case...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should not focus on the options but on what you want to achieve. My general comments regarding what you want to achieve:

- usually there is a trade-off between fast and small. -O3 means fast. Os means as fast as possible without increasing the size.
- you can use debug information (-g) with optimization (-O3), but the information is poor sometimes as there is not a direct connection between the source and the resulted code
- if you strip the debug information (-s) from the executable, you will not be able to debug that executable easily (you can have the debug information saved separately but this is another story)

Always use the manual (accessed by typing in a shell "man g++", or by searching on the internet "man g++") and search for the options if you are curios what it does. If you have a higher level question, then you can ask (for example the difference between -g1 and -g3 is explained in the manual)

As a suggestion: use -O3. If you develop constantly the program and use GDB as debugger use: -ggdb -g3.

Edit: Regarding on when to apply them: usually you do not worry about phase it is, you just send the options and the g++ takes care of them. When you will want something more specific, then you can check more.

Comment: GCC's info page (`info gcc`) is much more complete than its man page.